# Dealing with Invisible Referencers

Tags: oracle, foreign-key, constraint

Using Oracle database, suppose I have a parent table `parent` defined in schema `A`, and a child table `child` defined in schema `B`. To achieve this, schema `A` granted `references` privilege on `parent` to schema `B`.

Now, suppose I want to disable all foreign key constraints which reference `parent`, then I encounter the following issue: since `child` is in a different schema and schema `A` has no `select` privilege on `child`, `child`'s foreign key which references `parent` does not appear in schema `A`'s view of `all_constraints` and so schema `A` does not know to disable it.

Is there a way to work around this within schema `A` or must such a program be run with DBA privileges?